# Basic function call between a class and an activity

Tags: java, android

I have read many posts on Stackoverflow saying to do that kind of thing sending the context or the activity or the AppCompatActivity in parameter like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public SecondClass secondClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        secondClass = new SecondClass(this);    
    }

    public void updateView () {
        Log.d("CS", "MainActivity updateView");
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    public Context mContext;
    public SecondClass (Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mContext.updateView();
    }
}
```

But that give me error :

> "Cannot find symbol method updateView"

What did I done wrong ?

Comment: why are you calling updateView from Secondclass? what are you trying to do?

Comment: change your line for calling method as below

((MainActivity) context).updateView(); then it will work, and if you still get error then you need to declare one variuable for Activity activity and then use it as below like, 

((MainActivity) activity).updateView(); it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `Context` class has no method called `updateView()`.
what you can do is..

**Naiive Approach :**
in the activity, pass yourself as a `MainActivity` instance, then you can call the `updateView` method using that instance anytime you want.

**Recommended Approach :** Using the same concept but instead of passing yourself as a known class instance, you'll pass yourself as an `UpdateViewListener` (it's an interface you'll make), you'll basically need to implement an interface, let's call it `UpdateViewListener` and pass yourself as an `UpdateViewListener` in the `Second Class` constructor.
This interface should have a method called `updateView()`, so that any class implementing this interface will need to provide an implementation for this method, hence, in your `Second Class` you'll no longer care about what the `listener` is, as long as it implements the `UpdateViewListener` and has a method called `updateView()`, think of the interface as a contract.

This pattern is called `Observer Pattern`.

for more info refer [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your intentions are, but if you are invoking `MainActivity` methods then you need a `MainActivity` (or better you should extract those methods to an Interface)

```
public class SecondClass {
    public MainActivity mActivity;
    public SecondClass (MainActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mActivity.updateView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are doing appCompatActivity class to be downcast to Context. Context having no such method. if you want to do this method call you have to make the Convertion LIKE `((MainActivity)context).updateView()` otherwise you can make the Interface as Ahmed Ashraf said. or pass the MainActivity instance to the constructor as Ashraf said.